# Snapping vertices of the same line

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, snapping, combine

I am trying to automate a snapping of vertices that exist in the same polyline layer. I first implemented the Multipart to Singlepart tool which split up the up the lines (but lines which were once together still share a ORIG_FID). Now, I have lines which are very close to each other, which I'd like to connect. Is there a way to automate it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is an [article](https://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0412/use-the-snap-geoprocessing-tool-to-automate-editing.html) from 2012, still relevant for ArcPro